# systemd fails to start VPN service

Tags: expect, systemd-journald

I have a simple expect script name "vpnloginpractice.sh" that starts my VPN. The script located in "/etc/openvpn/" and works fine if I run it manually. I try using systemd to execute the script at startup, but it won't start the VPN. Below is the code of my VPN script and the service I created in directory /etc/systemd/system. What I'm doing wrong guys?

```
#------/etc/systemd/system/personal.service  permissions "-rwxrwxrwx" ---
[Unit]
Description=startVpnService

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/openvpn/vpnloginpractice.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target



#------Code of my VPN script with permissions "-rwxrwxrwx"----
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
set vpnuser "111111"
set vpnpassword "1234"
set rootpassword "12345"
spawn sudo openvpn {US California.ovpn}
expect "*password*:"
send "$rootpassword\r"
expect "Enter Auth Username: "
send "$vpnuser\r"
expect "Enter Auth Password:"
sleep 5
send "$vpnpassword\r"
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: add `sleep 5` after `expect eof` and see if it works for you.

Comment: Insert usual security concerns about storing passwords in plain text files, particularly world-readable ones.

Comment: `sleep` won't help since your timeout value is infinite. Have you listed the running processes on your system to see if it's still running?

Comment: Try specifying the full path to `openvpn` -- launching a "system service" would use a restrictive PATH I'd think.

Comment: You'll also want to check logs -- but I don't know where systemd stuff gets logged.